# Dart regular expression error Try calling using?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have

```
Error: Method 'group' cannot be called on 'RegExpMatch?' because it is potentially null.

 - 'RegExpMatch' is from 'dart:core'.

Try calling using ?. instead.

                final everything = match.group(0);
```

And my source code is here below, just a simple Regular expression.

Where should I fix this??

```
RegExp regExp = new RegExp(r'[0-9][0-9]');

RegExpMatch match = regExp.firstMatch(results.text);
         
final everything = match.group(0);
```

---

I changed the source code like this

```
  RegExp regExp = new RegExp(r'C(S|N)-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]');

  if (regExp.hasMatch(results.text)){
     
        RegExpMatch match = regExp.firstMatch(results.text);
         
        final everything = match!.group(0);
        _showMyDialog(everything);
          
  }
```

Still error happens.

```
lib/camera_preview_scanner.dart:77:44: Error: A value of type 'RegExpMatch?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'RegExpMatch' because 'RegExpMatch?' is nullable and 'RegExpMatch' isn't.

 - 'RegExpMatch' is from 'dart:core'.

                RegExpMatch match = regExp.firstMatch(results.text);

                                           ^

lib/camera_preview_scanner.dart:79:36: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'RegExpMatch' which excludes null.

 - 'RegExpMatch' is from 'dart:core'.

                final everything = match!.group(0);
```

---

Solution

use `RegExp!` instead of `RegExp`

```
  RegExp! regExp = new RegExp(r'C(S|N)-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]');

  if (regExp.hasMatch(results.text)){
     
        RegExpMatch match = regExp.firstMatch(results.text);
         
        final everything = match!.group(0);
        _showMyDialog(everything);
          
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
final everything = match!.group(0);
```

or better

```
if(match != null){ 
   final everything = match!.group(0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment I tried to use `match!` but in vain, I updated the article

Comment: Ah,problem is solved I use RegExpMatch? instead of RegExpMatch